# Can't Wireshark the USB bus: permissions

Tags: permissions, usb, wireshark

I am trying to monitor my USB traffic using Wireshark.

The [docs](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/USB) say "just do `sudo modprobe usbmon`". Well, that doesn't work:

```
vorac@laptop:~$ sudo modprobe usbmon
[sudo] password for vorac: 
vorac@laptop:~$ dumpcap -D
1. wlan0
2. nflog
3. nfqueue
4. eth1
5. any
6. lo (Loopback)
```

If I start Wireshark as root, the interfaces are there:

```
vorac@laptop:~$ sudo dumpcap -D
1. wlan0
2. nflog
3. nfqueue
4. eth1
5. usbmon1
6. usbmon2
7. any
8. lo (Loopback)
```

Wireshark Version 1.10.6 (v1.10.6 from master-1.10)
Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

How do I run Wireshark as regular user, being able to capture USB traffic?